# Is it surjective because of $K \subset H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ normal subgroups of $G$ s.t. $K \subset H$. If I define the following map: $\phi:G /K \to G/H, gK \mapsto gH$ then the claim is that it is surjective. Is it because we have that $K \subset H$ and hence $G /H \subset G/K$?

Comment: This map is well-defined since $K \subset H$ and surjective by definition. In fact, we do not even require $K$ and $H$ to be normal subgroups, any subgroups $K \subset H$ would work and the corresponding map $\phi$ would still be surjective (although no longer a homomorphism between groups).

Comment: No it is not true that $G/H \subset G/K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the application is surjective is trivial, since taken $gH\in G/H$, then  $\phi(gK)=gH$. The tricky part is proving that this is actually a well posed application. And this can be done as follows:
$$aK=bK\Rightarrow ab^{-1}\in K\subset H \Rightarrow   ab^{-1}\in H \Rightarrow aH=bH \Rightarrow \phi(aK)=\phi(bK)$$
Now you have just to prove that is an homomorphism (trivial), find its kernel and then apply first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 2):

More precisely, this is because of the $3^{ rd }$ *isomorphism theorem*: $H/K$ is a normal subgroup of $G/K$, and
$$(G/K)\big/(H/K)\simeq G/H.$$

What can be said of $G/H$ as compared to $G/K$ is that every $H$-coset is a union of $K$-cosets.

Comment: I just use this fact to proof this theorem, so I can't use it already..

Comment: Oh! I see. Note that at the end of your question, you do not have $G/H\subset G/K$,  but $G/H$ is a *quotient* of $G/K$.

Answer (score 1):

Since we aim to get a map *between coset sets*, but we can't avoid using coset *representatives*, we need to ensure that $g'\in gK\Rightarrow \phi(g'K)=\phi(gK)$ (good definition). But this is indeed the case, because by $K<H$ (see $(*)$ step):

\begin{alignat}{1}
g'\in gK &\Rightarrow g^{-1}g'\in K \\
&\stackrel{(*)}{\Rightarrow} g^{-1}g'\in H \\
&\Rightarrow g'\in gH \\
&\Rightarrow g'H=gH \\
&\Rightarrow \phi(g'K)=\phi(gK) \\
\end{alignat}

About surjectivity, notice that, by $K<H$, it is $\#G/K=[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]>[G:H]=\#G/H$ and use the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Finally, as long as you interpret $G/H$ and $G/K$ as quotient *sets* (not necessarily groups), the normality of $H$ and/or $K$ is not necessary for the map to be (well defined and) surjective.